# SCSS - pseudo element to create underline in the middle of sentence

Tags: html, css, sass, pseudo-element

I'm trying to underline some text in the middle of a sentence with a pseudo element. The underline needs to slightly cover the bottom of the text ("half decent") as in the picture below. The text that needs to be underlined is wrapped in the `underline` class.
[image: underlined text]

As seen in the code snippet I can't quite get it to dynamically underline the width of the class `underline` nor have it line up with the text in the class `underline`

```css
.h1{
  font-family: FreightBig Pro;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
}

.underline::after{
  content:"";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgba(7, 151, 144, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<span class="h1">I send a <span class="h1 underline">half decent</span> email </br> every week on the state of design.</span>
```

Comment: So what is your question? What part you actually want to underline?

Comment: @Kenny I edited the answer to make it more clear. the text that is wrapped in the class `underline` ("half decent") needs to be underlined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there

You need to add some more CSS to achieve that

Like

```
.underline {
    position: relative
}

.underline::after{
   content:"";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 12px;
   background: rgba(7, 151, 144, 0.5);
}
```

```css
.h1{
  font-family: FreightBig Pro;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
}

.underline {
  position: relative
 }
 
.underline::after{
  content:"";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgba(7, 151, 144, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<span class="h1">I send a <span class="h1 underline">half decent</span> email </br> every week on the state of design.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make label `position: relative;`

Set the position (`left, right, bottom`) of the `:after` element;

```css
.h1{
  font-family: FreightBig Pro;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 61px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.underline::after{
  content:"";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  background: rgba(7, 151, 144, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<span class="h1">I send a <span class="h1 underline">half decent</span> email </br> every week on the state of design.</span>
```